# Anyway to code the background code even more?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a webkit gradient background and a repeat picture on the same line of code in background-image. like

`background-image:url(../images/bloobg.png), -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* FF3.6+ */`

Wondering if i can add one more code or anything that will make the bloobg.png keep scrolling left. I tried to use jQuery and Java but i dont think im ready yet :[

-edit- i have supported the other browsers

```
#body { background:#9bd5eb;
background-image: url(../images/bloobg.png); /* fallback */
background-image:url(../images/bloobg.png),-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url(../images/bloobg.png),-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image:url(../images/bloobg.png), -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url(../images/bloobg.png), -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* IE10 */
background-image: url(../images/bloobg.png),  -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image:  url(../images/bloobg.png), linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* W3C */
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

also the website is [www.bloomooyogurt.com](http://www.bloomooyogurt.com)

-edit- I tried this out but didn't work can you see if there is a syntax error? For some reason the `@-webkit-keyframes move {` is in gray...

In the CSS file, I put

```
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }
@-moz-keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }
```

then i put

```
#body { background:#9bd5eb; 
background-image: url(../images/bloobg.png); /* fallback */
background-image:url(../images/bloobg.png),-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url(../images/bloobg.png),-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0), -webkit-animation: move 10s infinite; /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image:url(../images/bloobg.png), -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0), -moz-animation: move 10s infinite; /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url(../images/bloobg.png), -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* IE10 */
background-image: url(../images/bloobg.png),  -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image:  url(../images/bloobg.png), linear-gradient(bottom, #9bd5eb, #01aef0); /* W3C */
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

The only thing that changed was the gradient. It's just one color now.

Comment: "Keep scrolling left"? Do you mean a `background-position:fixed;`?

Comment: will that make my picture keep looping to the left? and going off screen?

Comment: The picture won't move, with respect to the viewport. Do you want to get an animated background instead?

Comment: i have background-attachment:fixed; which i believe stops the image ontop of the gradient from scrolling with the content but id like to animate it going left,edit perciecly

Comment: You can periodically move the background using the `background-position` CSS property. What browsers have to be supported?

Comment: I have Saf4+, Chrome, Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+,FF3.6+, IE10,Opera 11.10+,W3C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS animations to animate the background-position property. Here is an example (you will have to use browser prefixes):

```
@keyframes bgMove {
    0% { background-position: 0 0, 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: 100% 0, 0 0; }
}
.foo {
    animation: bgMove 5s infinite;
}
```

Comment: would that go right beneath my #body{..}? and do i have to define the .foo somewhere?

Comment: i dont think my @keyframes are working im using joomla extplorer plugin and it show it up as gray :C

Comment: .foo is just a bogus name, apply those styles to the required element/s. Keep in mind you have to add the browser prefixes (-webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, and -o-).

Comment: so i just add animation: bgMove 5s infinite; inside the #body{..} below the background-image: url...;? and do @-webkit-keyframes bgMove {...} then the other browser prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

Your gradient currently only works in one browser.

`body
{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9bd5eb, #01aef0);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #9bd5eb),color-stop(1, #01aef0));
    background: linear-gradient(#9bd5eb, #01aef0);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#9bd5eb, #01aef0); 
}`

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as a comment, as it isn't really an answer to the question?